# What causes a planted seed not have leaves

Tags: diagnosis

I started a avacado tree from seed and it is about two feet tall but it only has new leaves at the top of it and the rest is bare stalk. what do I need to do to make it make more leaves.

Comment: Hello Tammie.  Welcome.   Could you please take a picture and post it?  It will be helpful in answering your question.   Do you have it by a sunny window or have a grow light for it?

Comment: I have it sitting by my kitchen window where it should be getting good light but where I live right now it is winter time and the light isnt as good

Comment: I am not sure how to add a picture to this site

Comment: Below your answer are 3 links 'share edit flag'.  You need to click edit.  Then in the box where you write your wrote your question will be a line of icon.  The first icon is the letter 'B'.   The 6th icon from the left looks like a mountain w/a sun.  Click that link.  Then click browse.  Find the photo on your computer and click open.  The last step is to hit add picture.

Answer (score 1):

Usually excessive elongation means that the plant isn't getting enough light and is trying to reach up to a less shaded area.  What kind of lighting are you giving it?

Comment: It is getting just regular light from my kitchen window and it is wonter here so the light is not as bright

Comment: See if you can find a brighter window or failing that give it supplemental lighting.